# Streaming an API using request module

Tags: node.js, api, request, streaming

The API endpoint I need to access provides live streaming option only. But the need is for a regular non streaming API. Using the request node module can I achieve this?

Comment: Live streaming of what?  Explain exactly what the current API does and then explain what you're trying to do that is different than that.  As it stands now, there's way too little info in your question to even understand what problem you're trying to solve.

Comment: The API endpoint is a streaming endpoint - meaning it does not close the connection but keeps on sending the data . The API in question here is Docker remote API (GET /containers/(id)/stats). A more popular example of streaming API will be  Twitter streaming API. I don't have a requirement of reading from the stream continuously but at a frequency of 10 ,15 minutes. Looking at the section https://github.com/request/request#streaming I am not understanding this is possible or not

Answer (score 0):

You can hook up to the stream on your server and store data that arrives in the stream locally on the server in a database and then when a REST request comes in for some data, you look in your local database and satisfy the request from that database (the traditional, non-streaming way).

Other than that, I can't figure out what else you might be trying to do.  You cannot "turn a streaming API into a non-streaming one".  They just aren't even close to the same thing.  A streaming API is like subscribing to a feed of information.  You don't make a request, new data is just sent to you when it's available.  A typical non-streaming API is that a client makes a specific request and the server responds with data for that specific request.

Here's a discussion of the Twitter streaming API that might be helpful: https://dev.twitter.com/streaming/overview